# Change color of individual prefab instance after it was touched Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started making a 2d game, where an Individual Prefab Instance has to change color after being touched. I'm new to programming in C# and I've scoured the internet for hours but I still can't find an answer which works. I tried adding `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;` to the script on my prefab but it changes the color of all instantiated prefabs. My Unity version is 2019.2.3f1. Please help me.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                 if (hit.transform.name == "square")
                 {
                      Destroy(gameObject);
                      print("TOUCHED");
                      GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the whole method where you use GetComponent

Comment: @Josh ,Ok I added it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

Each of your instances of this script is running that method simultaneously so the Raycast and hit is processed on all of them.

In general it makes little sense to me that you do `Destroy(gameObject)` and right after it try to access `GetComponent<Renderer>` of the object you just destroyed ...

---

It is a bit unclear what you wanted to do but I guess it was something like

```
if (hit.transform.name == "square")
{
    print("TOUCHED");
    hit.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
}
```

Which only colors the object that was hit. You would also only need exactly **one** instance of this component in your scene!

---

A way better way would be that each item detects the click itself! You can do this e.g. implementing the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) interface like

```
public TouchDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        Debug.Log("I was touched!", this);
        GetComponemt<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

This would go on each object that should detect a click/touch.

Notes:

- In newer versions UI was moved to a Package in the PackageManager, make sure it is installed.
- According objects either have to be UI or require a `Collider` and on the `Camera` a `PhysicsRaycaster` component.